# How do I insert a picture into the Notes app?

Tags: ios, iphone, graphics, notes.app

I use the Notes app for keeping track and sharing the extended notes with fellow physicians in cardiology studies. There are a lot of pros to this app and I would find it very much useful if I could insert pictures into specific areas within Notes. (a video would make it even better). How is it possible to customize this for a such purpose and is there an alternative to this solution?

Answer (score 6):

The iOS Notes app is not able to insert pictures. At best it will paste a url to an image.

I suggest you use another note app such as [Evernote](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/evernote/id281796108?mt=8) or [Notability](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/notability-take-notes-annotate/id360593530?mt=8).

Answer (score 4):

You could just wait for the next iPhone update. While it's not guaranteed to have the ability to add photos, I believe it's likely that it will have the ability to do so. That's because one of the [new features in Mountain Lion](http://www.apple.com/macosx/mountain-lion/features.html#notes) is a Notes app which synchronizes with iCloud, and one of it's features is adding pictures to notes:

> Notes in OS X Mountain Lion is designed for whatever’s on your mind. Think it up. Jot it down. Make it even more noteworthy with photos, images, and attachments.

[image: Notes on OS X Mountain Lion]

Comment: In light of http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1114/can-we-open-questions-about-mountain-lion maybe this should be a comment instead of an answer but I could be wrong and/or biased :)

Comment: I suspect that if you can source the answer by linking to Apple's website, you're probably not breaking any NDA by posting this, as I first feared. :-)

Answer (score 2):

That was one of the things I also noticed and found a bit strange - therefore, I developed the app **My Photo Note**.

You can let the app **set a link of your photo note into the iPhone calendar** - tapping the link will open up the photo note in My Photo Note.

My Photo Note is also not free ($1.99 for the full version), but you can try the lite version for free: [My Photo Note](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-photo-note-lite-taking/id479346628?ls=1&mt=8)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add pictures to the Notes app at present. [NoteMaster](http://itunes.apple.com/app/notemaster-notes-images-synced/id297921531?mt=8) is a paid app that lets you add images and make pretty notes easily. Some of the other features include:

- rich text
- sync with Google docs
- create and manage lists & to-dos

It isn't free though, and costs $3.99.

---

There are a bazillion note-taking apps out there that are better than the default — it's almost like the "Hello world" of apps, and [this article](http://iphone.appstorm.net/roundups/productivity-roundups/100-apps-for-taking-notes-on-your-iphone/) reviews 100 of them!

Answer (score 0):

iLA is a brilliant tool designed for notes, project planning, deep learning, collaborating , brainstorming and the like. Of course you can insert pictures in card, make notes to card, create stack from cards (categorizing), and make a desktop of one topic. Sharing knowledge becomes extremely easy and fun!

It is available on [Apple Appstore from this link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ila-cs/id578297245?ls=1&mt=8).

Also "Individual Learning Tool," the book about iLA, is available [on iBookStore for free](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/individual-learning-tool/id597180343?mt=11).

Answer (score -4):

Use Evernote that is the best note taking website/app